# Can we consider the "fill the earth" commandment as fulfilled?

Tags: pregnancy-birth

As we can see, the Earth is full with us (humans) and with our animals. Can we consider with it the ancient commandment as fulfilled?

Which is important from this view: if it is fulfilled, it means it doesn't bind any more (i.e. there is no need to have many children with the intention to fulfill this commandment [although it could be needed for other reasons]).

Comment: @Double AA: This is not the same question. It is asking about the concept of "filling the earth" which corresponds to the idea that HaShem created the world in its fullness. (Yalkut Shimoni, Bereishit 8.) As opposed to the halachic requirement to reproduce in your  link above. The question should be reopened and a more detailed answer be allowed.